# Best way to give user the option to make a menu, mega menu?

Tags: theme-development, menus

i am developing a WordPress theme for themeforest and i was wondering whats the appropriate way to give the option to user to make a menu, mega menu. currently my way is that user has to go to Apperances-> menu then under screen option the user has to tick the css classes and then add mega class to the menu item to make that menu item appear mega menu which doesn't seems right cause its difficult for user to go through all that to make a menu mega. so i was wondering is there a more appropriate and professional way to handle this?

Comment: Do you mean from a UI/UX point of view, or an already-built solution you can just drop in? (Not that I know anything about either!)

Comment: from UI/UX point of view cause any solution is better than this. if wordpress support some kinda solution for this issue than please let me know cause it will be a standard solution. anyhow if u know any other way please let me know thank you